# Read txt file with separator is space

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read text file. The file is like this:
17430147 17277121 17767569 17352501 17567841 17650342 17572001

I want the result:

17430147

17277121

17767569

17352501

17567841

17650342

17572001

So, i try some codes:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.txt', header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
```

or

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

From those codes, the error like this:

```
ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 75262 and found 154
```

Then i try this code:

```
file = open("train.txt", "r")

data = []

for i in file:
    i = i.replace("\n", "")
    data.append(i.split(" "))
```

But i think there are missing value in txt file:

```
'2847',
  '2848',
  '2849',
  '1947',
  '2850',
  '2851',
  '2729',
  ''],
 ['2852',
  '2853',
  '2036',
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to read the text file as a string of values.

```
with open('train.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
list_of_values = lines[0].split(' ')
```

Here, *`list_of_values`* looks like:
['17430147',
'17277121',
'17767569',
'17352501',
'17567841',
'17650342',
'17572001']

Now, to create a DataFrame out of this list, simply execute:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(list_of_values)
```

This will give a pandas DataFrame with a single column with values read from the text file.
[image]

If only different values that exist in the text file are required to be obtained, then the list *`list_of_values`* can be directly used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.T` method to transpose your dataframe.

```
data = pd.read_csv("train.txt", delim_whitespace=True).T
```